# VBA Excel - Pop up message when value between two values

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a code that will pop up a message box when a value (ie in cell A1) is not between the value of two seperated cell values.
For instance, display a pop message when the value A1 is lower than A2 or if higher then A3;
Can anyone help me with this one?
Thx in adv;
Brgds, Jimmy

Comment: You need to first try this on your own and then ask for any help.

Comment: _I am looking for a code_ - You are on wrong site.

Comment: Google for "VBA If Msgbox examples".

Comment: You can also look into Data Validation.  Excel already has something that you can set to do this.

Comment: SO --> Not a coding service.

Does it really have to be code? 
I think you're looking for tab "Data" on the Ribbon and then "Data Validation"

Answer (score 1):

Use following simple sub.

```
Sub CHeckVal()
    If Range("A1").Value < Range("A2") Or Range("A1").Value > Range("A3") Then
        MsgBox Range("A1").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hook similar code into Worksheet_Change event and you'll actually get the Pop-up when you change the value; Otherwise you'd have to run the macro manually each time the value changes.